# How to prevent the Picker control's selection box from automatically popping up

Tags: mvvm

The picker in the MAUI project is located on page A. When returning to page A from page B, the picker will trigger a pop-up selection box. How can we avoid this?

I set its attribute 'IsEnabled' to false, which is valid for Android API v28 and above, but invalid in versions below it

'''

```
   MainPage.xaml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MauiAppForPicker.MainPage">
    
        <Button Text="To A" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    
    </ContentPage>
    MainPage.cs:
    
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            int count = 0;
    
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(A), true);
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    A.Xaml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MauiAppForPicker.A"
                 Title="A">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Picker Title="Select...">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>1</x:String>
                    <x:String>2</x:String>
                    <x:String>3</x:String>
                    <x:String>4</x:String>
                    <x:String>5</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
            <Button Text="To B"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    
    A.cs:
    public partial class A : ContentPage
    {
        public A()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(B),true);
        }
    }
    
    B.xaml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MauiAppForPicker.B"
                 Title="B">
```

'''

Comment: Instead of only describing your code and the problem, please show the relevant bits and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I found a rule that if you jump from page A to page B (which has a Picker control), and then from page B to page C, when you return from page C to page B, the Picker control on page B automatically opens a pop-up window,When the initial page of the program is page B, returning to page B from page C will not pop up the Picker's selection window

Comment: I don't think you'll receive useful help or answers if you don't provide more context and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When entering from MainPge, redirecting to page A, then jumping from page A to page B, and then returning from page B to page A, a Picker selection box pops up, which only appears when the API is version 28 and below